# Escape single and double back slashes

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace a string using regex, however I can't seem to find a way to escape the single backslashes for the regex with the double backslashes of the string.

My string literal (this is being read from a text file, as is)

```
-s \"t\"
```

and I want to replace it with (again, as a string literal)

```
-s \"n\"
```

The best I have been able to come up with is

```
schedule = Regex.Replace(schedule, "-s\s\\\"\w\\\"", "-s \\\"n\\\"");
```

The middle argument doesn't compile though, because of the single and double backslashes. It will accept one or the other, but not both (regardless of weather I use @).

I don't use regexes that much so it may be a simple one but I'm pretty stuck!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because `\` have a special meaning both for strings and regular expressions so it normally needs to be double escaped unless you use `@` and added to the problem here is the presence of `"` itself inside the string which needs to be escaped.

Try the following:

```
schedule = Regex.Replace(schedule, @"-s\s\\""\w\\""", @"-s \""n\""");
```

After using `@`, `\` doesn't have a special meaning inside strings, but it still have a special meaning inside regular expression expression so it needs to be escaped only once if it is needed literally.

Also now you need to use `""` to escape `"` inside the string *(how would you escape it otherwise, since `\` doesn't have a special meaning anymore)*.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't compile either.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely found it, but it's replacing it with an extra slash, the replaced string is `-s \\"n\\"`

Comment: @BaliC Sorry for this, the replacement string isn't a regular expression so we don't need double `\\`, check edit please.

Comment: @BaliC You are welcome, sorry for all the edits as I was answering rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var schedule = @"-s \""t\""";
// value is -s \"t\"
schedule = Regex.Replace(schedule, @"-s\s\\""\w\\""", @"-s \""n\""");
// value is -s \"n\"
```

The escaping is complicated because `\` and `"` have special meanings both in how you encode strings in C# and in regex. The search pattern is (without any escaping) the C# string `-s\s\\"\w\\"`, which tells regex to look for a literal `\` and a literal `"`. The replacement string is `-s \"n\"`, because you don't need to escape the backslashes in a replacement string.

You could, of course, write this with normal strings (`"..."`) instead of verbatim strings (`@"..."`), but it'd get *way* messier.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that makes sense, I will have to learn this stuff one day!